# Wedge product and change of variables

Tags: differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus, exterior-algebra

The question is:

> Let $\phi ： \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$ map and let $y = \phi(x)$ be the change of variables. Show that
>
> $$dy_1\wedge\dots\wedge dy_n = (\operatorname{det}D\phi(x))\cdot dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n.$$

I tried $n = 2, 3$ but still didn't get any rule. Do we need to do this under integral?

Comment: In addition to Michael Albanese's answer, it is not uncommon to *define* the determinant of $D\phi(x)$ as $D\phi(x,dx_1) \wedge \ldots \wedge D\phi(x, dx_n) = \det (D\phi(x)) dx_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_n$ (remember that the Jacobian acts on both a point $x$ and some vector or differential or what-have-you).  As Michael has proven, this is equivalent to the determinant you usually see from matrix algebra.  This gives a nice way of not having to resort to matrix calculations to talk about determinants.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have $y = (y_1, \dots, y_n) = (\phi_1, \dots, \phi_n)$ so 
\begin{align*}
dy_1\wedge\dots\wedge dy_n &= d\phi_1\wedge\dots\wedge d\phi_n\\ 
&= \left(\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial x_1}dx_1 + \dots +\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial x_n}dx_n\right)\wedge\dots\wedge\left(\frac{\partial \phi_n}{\partial x_1}dx_1 + \dots +\frac{\partial \phi_n}{\partial x_n}dx_n\right)\\
&= \sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\frac{\partial\phi_1}{\partial x_{\sigma(1)}}\dots\frac{\partial\phi_n}{\partial x_{\sigma(n)}}dx_{\sigma(1)}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{\sigma(n)}\\
&= \sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial\phi_i}{\partial x_{\sigma(i)}}\right)dx_{\sigma(1)}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{\sigma(n)}\\
&= \left(\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\operatorname{sign}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial\phi_i}{\partial x_{\sigma(i)}}\right)dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n\\
&= \det\left(\frac{\partial\phi_i}{\partial x_j}\right)dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n\\
&= \det(D\phi)dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n
\end{align*}

where we have used the fact that for an $n\times n$ matrix $A = (a_{ij})$, the determinant is given by $$\det A = \sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\operatorname{sign}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^na_{i\sigma(j)}$$ as can be seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n.C2.A0.C3.97.C2.A0n_matrices).

Comment: In the 4th row of your answer, Do you mean it is the sum of $n!$ formulas?

Comment: In the fourth row I have just replaced the product $$\frac{\partial\phi_1}{\partial x_{\sigma(1)}}\dots\frac{\partial\phi_n}{\partial x_{\sigma(n)}}$$ by the expression $$\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial\phi_i}{\partial x_{\sigma(i)}}.$$

Comment: I mean this row: $\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\frac{\partial\phi_1}{\partial x_{\sigma(1)}}\dots\frac{\partial\phi_n}{\partial x_{\sigma(n)}}dx_{\sigma(1)}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{\sigma(n)}$

Comment: There are $n!$ terms in that sum, yes. Is that what you were asking?