# A few questions about Jacobian determinants in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

There is a deduction being made on page 196 of Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry I" which I am not following.

**Theorem**: Any nonsingular point $ x \in X $ of an $ n$-dimensional variety has a neighbourhood $ U $ such that $ \Omega^{r}[U] $ is a free $ k[U]$-module of rank $ n\choose r $.

We can see immediately that by the theorem, the module $ \Omega^{n}[U] $ is of rank $ 1 $ over $ k[U]. $ So if $ \omega \in k[U], $ then an expression for $ \omega $ depends on the choice of the local parameters $ u_{1},\dots,u_{n}, $ so we have $$ \omega = gdu_{1} \wedge \dots \wedge du_{n} \text{ with } g \in k[U]. $$

He then says:

> We determine what this dependence is. Let $ v_{1},\dots, v_{n} $ be
>   another $ n $ regular functions on $ X $ such that $ v_{1}-v_{1}(x),\dots,v_{n}-v_{n}(x) $ are local parameters at any 
>   point $ x \in U. $ Then also $$ \Omega^{1}[U] = k[U]dv_{1} \oplus
> \dots \oplus k[U]dv_{n}, $$ and in particular, the $ du_{i} $ can be
>   expressed $$ du_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} h_{ij}dv_{j} $$ for $ i = 1,\dots, n. $

This is all more or less clear so far. The author then says:

> Since $ d_{x}u_{1},\dots,d_{x}u_{n} $ form a basis of the vector space
>   $ (T_{x}X)^{*} $ for each $ x \in U, $ it follows from the equation
>   above that $ \text{det}|h_{ij}(x)| \neq 0. $

The matrix $ (h_{ij}(x)) $  is apparently called the Jacobian determinant  of the functions $ u_{1},\dots,u_{n} $ with respect to $ v_{1},\dots,v_{n}. $

I guess this is basically linear algebra, but I'm not seeing why $ (h_{ij}(x)) $ is nonsingular. Is it because since $$ a_{1}d_{x}u_{1}+\dots + a_{n}d_{x}u_{n} = 0 \Rightarrow  a_{1} = \dots = a_{n} = 0. $$

I'm guessing that this implies that $ h_{ij} \neq 0 \; $ for all $ i,j = 1,\dots,n. $ I'm not sure this necessary means that $ \text{det}|h_{ij}| \neq 0, $ since there are non-singular non-zero matrices. Where am I going wrong?

Furthermore, apparently if you substitute the equation $ du_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} h_{ij}d_{x}v_{j} $ in the expression for $ \omega, $ you can show that $$ \omega = g\;J\Bigg( \frac{u_{1},\dots,u_{n}}{v_{1},\dots,v_{n}}\Bigg) dv_{1} \wedge \dots \wedge dv_{n}. $$

I'm not sure how we come by this last equation. To start of, $$ \omega = g\; \sum_{j=1}^{n} h_{1j}dv_{1} \wedge \dots \wedge \sum_{j=1}^{n} h_{nj}dv_{n}. $$

I'm not entirely sure how to obtain the Jacobian deterterminant from this step.

Comment: Do you buy that at each point $x$, the matrix $h_{ij}(x)$ takes one basis ($du_k$) to another ($dv_k$)?

Comment: @RghtHndSd I do

Comment: @RghtHndSd Ah I see. So it has to be invertible by default, though that does feel like a less direct way to see that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, at each point $x$, the matrix $(h_{ij}(x))$ takes the basis $(du_k)_k$ to the basis $(dv_k)_k$. Any linear map taking one basis to another is invertible, and hence has nonzero determinant.

Edit: I missed the 2nd question, meaning this is an incomplete answer.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367949/wedge-product-and-change-of-variables) for a proof of the 2nd bit.

Comment: @KReiser: good find. I recommend making that into an answer, and it be selected as the answer to this question.